# Defining my own range function that returns a list

Tags: python, list, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to get rid of this yeild and the '%g' statement and replace it with a return statement if anyone has any idea about how to do that. As well as that I am trying to make it so this truly works like a function and you can pass variables into it and get the range as a list, but I'm not sure how to do that either. Any help would be appreciated. I am very lost on this one.

The code is supposed to act as a range function but returns a list.

```
def myRange(start, stop=None, step=None):

    if stop == None:
        stop = start

    if step == None:
        step = 1

    while True:
        if step > 0 and start >= stop:
            break
        elif step < 0 and start <= stop:
            break
        yield ("%g" % start)
        start = start + step

lyst = myRange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1)
for num in lyst:
    print (num)
```

Comment: For a start, why don't you ``append`` the items to a list instead of yielding them? Why do you *string format* the numbers, anyways? Finally, why not just ``return list(range(start, stop, step))``?

Comment: What should I do instead of string format them? I'd like to just get rid of the whole yield line of code.

Comment: Since you want a list -- why not build one? Since you don't want to string-format the number -- why not use the number as-is?

Comment: I get this error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable - when I remove the line of code. As well as that I need to get rid of the - lyst = myRange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1)
for num in lyst:
    print (num)

Comment: You have to *replace* that line, not remove it. Do you know how to append to a list?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `yield`, just make a variable to hold the resulting list and continually add to it:

```
    lst = []
    while True:
        if step > 0 and start >= stop:
            break
        elif step < 0 and start <= stop:
            break
        lst.append("%g" % start)
        start += step
    return lst
```